# Question about the inverse of the Implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

Look at the following equation system:

$3x+y-z+u^4=0 \\ x-y+2z+u=0 \\2x+2y-3z+u=0  $

> Prove that the system doesn't fix $(x,y,z)$ as a function of
>   $u\in(-\delta,\delta)$ for all $\delta>0$.

My question is If I prove that the assumptions of the implicit function theorem don't apply in this case, specifically that \begin{bmatrix}
\overrightarrow{\frac{df}{dx} }&\overrightarrow{ \frac{df}{dy} }& \overrightarrow{\frac{df}{dz}}
\end{bmatrix} isn't invertible for $f(x,y,u,z)=(3x+y-z+u^4,x-y+2z+u,2x+2y-3z+u)$ . Can we conclude from that that the system doesn't fix $(x,y,z)$ as a function of $u\in(-\delta,\delta)$ for all $\delta>0$?

If not, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general that's not enough. (The implicit function theorem gives a sufficient but not a necessary condition.)

But in this case, if you let $u=0$, the system becomes
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & -3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
,
$$
which has nontrivial solutions (since the determinant is zero), namely $(x,y,z)=(-t,7t,4t)$, $t \in \mathbf{R}$. So the system doesn't even define the values $x(0)$, $y(0)$, $z(0)$ uniquely.